# Typecasting Arrays for Variable Width Access

Tags: c, memory, casting, hardware, buffer-overrun

Sorry, I am not sure if I wrote the title accurately.

But first, here are my constraints:

1. Array[], used as a register map, is declared as an unsigned 8-bit array (uint8_t),
   this is so that indexing(offset) is per byte.
2. Data to be read/written into the array has varying width (8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit).
3. Very Limited Memory and Speed is a must.

What are the caveats in doing the following

```
uint8_t some_function(uint16_t offset_addr) //16bit address
{
  uint8_t Array[0x100];
  uint8_t data_byte = 0xAA;
  uint16_t data_word;
  uint32_t data_double = 0xBEEFFACE;

\\ A. Storing wider-data into the array
*((uint32_t *) &Array[offset_addr]) = data_double;

\\ B. Reading multiple-bytes from the array
data_word = *((uint16_t *) &Array[offset_addr]);
 
  return 0;
}
```

I know i could try writing the data per byte, but that would be slow due to bit shifting.

Is there going to be a significant problem with this usage?
I have run this on my hardware and have not seen any problems so far, but I want to take note of potential problems this implementation might cause.

Comment: There's really nothing wrong with casting your pointers to different types for width access if that's what you are wondering/asking. I don't believe there would be a performance lost since the operation happens atomically

Comment: On the contrary, @Nina, casting the pointers to incompatible types and then dereferencing them violates the strict aliasing rule.  Undefined behavior results.  Even if the compiler just does the obvious thing (which it is not obligated to do), misaligned accesses resulting from this approach will cause reduced performance on some systems and traps on some others.

Comment: That makes sense @JohnBollinger I did not consider allignment; however, if you do understand how the compiler would behave and how the system would treat each operation then it should be fine yes?

Comment: If you do this, be aware that the whole thing is not defined by the C Standard so you are relying on the good will of the compiler vendor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there going to be a significant problem with this usage?

It produces undefined behavior.  Therefore, even if in practice that manifests as you intend on your current C implementation, hardware, program, and data, you might find that it breaks unexpectedly when something (anything) changes.

Even if the compiler implements the cast and dereference in the obvious way (which it is not obligated to do, because UB) misaligned accesses resulting from your approach will at least slow many CPUs, and will produce traps on some.

The standard-conforming way to do what you want is this:

```
uint8_t some_function(uint16_t offset_addr) {
  uint8_t Array[0x100];
  uint8_t data_byte = 0xAA;
  uint16_t data_word;
  uint32_t data_double = 0xBEEFFACE;

\\ A. Storing wider-data into the array
  memcpy(Array + offset_addr, &data_double, sizeof data_double);

\\ B. Reading multiple-bytes from the array
  memcpy(&data_word, Array + offset_addr, sizeof data_word);
 
  return 0;
}
```

This is not necessarily any slower than your version, and it has defined behavior as long as you do not overrun the bounds of your array.

Comment: Question: What if I wanted the offset to be treated as a different type rather than uint8? For example, I have a uint16_t* array then +2 would be (sizeof(uint16_t)+2) however I wanted the pointer offset to be treated as a uint8_t, so in this case could I do `memcpy((uint8_t*)array+offset...)`

Comment: Yes, @Nina, if you want the offset to be interpreted in units the size of a `uint8_t`, but the array has some wider element type, then the approach you present will achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably fine. Many have done things like this. C performs well with this kind of thing.

Two things to watch out for:

1. Buffer overruns.  You know those zero-days like Eternal Blue and hacks like WannaCry? Many of them exploited bugs in code like yours. Malicious input caused the code to write too much stuff into data structures like your `uint8_t Array[0x100]`. Be careful. Avoid allocating buffers on the stack (as function-local variables) as you have done because clobbering the stack is exploitable. Make them big enough. Check that you don't overrun them.
2. Machine byte ordering vs. network byte ordering, aka [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). If these data structures move from machine to machine over the net you may get into trouble.

Comment: Thanks you!
The actual implementation of the data structure is on a global scale, so it is most probably in the .data section. 
As for the endianness, so far, there is no need to run the code on a different machine/system.
nevertheless, I will take note on these. really appreciate it!

Comment: It's also easy for cybercreeps to clobber things in your .data section to get your program to run their malicious code. Be vigilant. (Security is a big reason people migrate to languages like Java / c# / rust / python / go.)

Comment: Rest assured, the machine this will run to does not have internet access. haha. it is a low-level program that runs on fpga/softprocessors.

Comment: OK. But still be careful.